# python-tkinter error (unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Entry' and 'float')

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling

```
from tkinter import*
def final_calculation (event):
    steal = float(amount_steal.get())
    output_steal = (amount_steal * steal_c02 *c02_coal)
    sumEntry.insert(0, sum)

root = Tk()
steal_c02 = float (5.5)
c02_coal = float (0.94)

amount_steal = Entry(root)
amount_steal.pack(side=LEFT)

equalButton = Button(root, text= "=")

equalButton.bind('<Button-1>', final_calculation)
equalButton.pack(side=LEFT)

sumEntry = Entry(root)
sumEntry.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

## and the error i get is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in 
__call__
 return self.func(*args)
 File "<ipython-input-32-5bd239601a92>", line 4, in final_calculation
 output_steal =  float(amount_steal * steal_c02 *c02_coal)
*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Entry' and 'float'
```

It all works fine until i try to calculate the sum please note im a complete noob when it comes to tkinter any help would be very useful 
kind regards 
49.95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that in line 4, instead of using the variable `steal` (which you have assigned the value in `amount_steel`), you have used the `amount_steel` variable, which does **not** store the value in the textbox, but rather the object representing the textbox.

To fix this, simply change line 4 to:

```
output_steal = (steal * steal_c02 * c02_coal
```

---

However, there is another issue here, which could potentially occur if the user enters a value which isn't convertible to a `float`: if the user enters a value like "twenty" or "1.1.", then your program will stop. This is fixable by testing to ensure that the entered value is indeed convertible to a `float`, like so:

```
def final_calculation(event):
    steal = amount_steal.get()
    try:
      float(steal)
    except ValueError:
      #code to notify user of invalid value
      return #don't return anything to stop the calculation

#rest of code here
```

Comment: thank you so much i must of spent a good 3 hours scratching my head at this. another thing was on line 5 i had to change 'sum' to 'output_steal'